# Wizard pattern on IOS: Layout guidelines

Tags: android, ios, interface, wizard, tablet

I want to build an app for android and iOS that uses a five-step wizard to create an asset.

Are there any established design patterns for tablets for a wizard pattern of this sort? I was thinking perhaps tabs across the top or bottom indicating the steps, along with a progress bar. Some other options might be a swipe system - swipe to the next step or something like that.

Additionally, I'd like to know what the options are for a phone layout.

If there's a well-established pattern, it's probably better to use that.

Thanks!

Edit: For what it's worth, I realize that Xcode might actually provide a template for this. I will be using Phonegap, however, and as such I won't be able to use those templates.

Comment: Have a look at how they did this: [Step Forn Wizad](http://codecanyon.net/item/step-form-wizard/full_screen_preview/8591111). It is nice because it lets you painlessly toggle between steps even on mobile viewport size.

Comment: You can use the following library if you decide to code using Android Studio. https://github.com/shivasurya/materialsteppers

Comment: Can a user jump between step or is the visual representation of the steps just to inform of where they are in the process?

Answer (score 1):

One pattern you could consider is the Wizard layout described by Oracle's [Alta UI guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/mobile/pattern/wizard.html), and implemented in the [Oracle JET toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/index.html). The iOS version looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of a Train implemented by Oracle JET]

Answer (score 0):

Instagram's App, at least for smartphones (not tablets), has a kind of wizard style get forward to complete your new Instagram picture process. See https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android

Answer (score 0):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f68M4k.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>